# AngularJS: Handling multiple responses in controller and view

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm building a news app. User can post different types of news from their home page. Home Page

```
<uib-tabset active="active">
  <uib-tab index="0" heading="All News">
    <news-feed poststype="1" username="userName"></news-feed>
  </uib-tab>
  <uib-tab index="1" heading="Internation">
    <news-feed poststype="3" username="userName"></news-feed>
  </uib-tab>
  <uib-tab index="2" heading="Regional">
    <news-feed poststype="7" username="userName"></news-feed>
  </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

News feed is a directive that I injected in home page.

This is the view: (news feed view)

```
<div class="post-textarea">
  <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="vm.currentPost.content"></textarea>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.addPost(vm.currentPost.content)">Post</a>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div>
  <ul class="media-list">
    <li class="media post" ng-repeat="post in vm.posts">
      <div class="post-main">
        <div class="post-content">{{post.content}}</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It has a text area using which users can post new news updates. But when a user publishes it, it show reflect in all the three news feeds. because user can set more than one category to a news posts, which I'm not including here to reduce complexity.

But it's not getting reflected in all the three tabs.

This is my controller (news feed controller):

```
(function() {
  angular
    .module('myApp.newsFeed', [])

  .factory('newsFeedService', function($http) {
    var baseUrl = 'api/';

    return {

      postCurrentPost: function(newPost) {
        var dataPost = {
          newPost: newPost
        };
        return $http({
          method: 'post',
          url: baseUrl + 'postCurrentPost',
          data: dataPost,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          }
        });
      }
    };
  })

  .directive('newsFeed', function() {
    var controller = function($routeParams, newsFeedService, $scope, focus) {
      var vm = this;

      // Add a news post
      vm.addPost = function(newPost) {
        var currentPost = vm.currentPost;
        currentPost.created_at = new Date();
        currentPost.content = ""; //clear post textarea
        if (newPost) {
          newsFeedService.postCurrentPost(newPost).success(function(data) {
            vm.posts = data;
          });
        }
      };

    };

    var template = '<button>{{vm.poststype}}</button>';

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        poststype: '@',
        username: '='
      },
      controller: controller,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true, //required in 1.3+ with controllerAs
      templateUrl: 'app/newsFeed.html'
        //template: template
    };
  });
})();
```

But my current setup shows it only in one tab. Or user has to reload the page.
Is there a way to reflect a new change in all the 3 tabs?

My PHP code (backend) looks like this:

```
function postCurrentPost()
{

    $requestData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    $newPost = $requestData->newPost;
    $content=validate_input($newPost);

   //code to save it to db comes here

   //fetch all news; I have functions returning international and regional news
   //how can I handle it in angular view
    $data=getAllPosts();
    return $data;
}

function getAllPosts()
{
  //returns all news
}

function international()
{
  //returns international news
}

function regional()
{
  //returns regional news
}
```

Since it's a directive that I injected to home page, and all the three tabs share the same page code, how can I do this?

Comment: using same model won't work ?

Comment: like how.......? @manish

Answer (score 0):

Since you are wanting to share one model you can create a controller for the main view and define the model which I just named newsData:

**Home Page Controller**

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.newsData = [{
    id: 1,
    type: 1,
    content: 'first post'
  }];
});
```

This model will be passed into your directive via an attribute called news-data

**Home Page**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  <uib-tabset active="active">
    <uib-tab index="0" heading="All News">
      <news-feed poststype="1" username="userName" news-data="main.newsData"></news-feed>
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="1" heading="Internation">
      <news-feed poststype="3" username="userName" news-data="main.newsData"></news-feed>
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="2" heading="Regional">
    <news-feed poststype="7" username="userName" news-data="main.newsData"></news-feed>
    </uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset>
</body>
```

Now anything that you want shared in your directive controller, including the newsData array, needs to be passed in via bindToController rather than into the isolate scope of the directive

**newsFeed Directive**

```
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
    username: '='
  },
  controller: controller,
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  bindToController: {
    poststype: '@',
    newsData: '='
  }, //required in 1.3+ with controllerAs
  templateUrl: 'app/newsFeed.html'
    //template: template
};
```

Now in your directive controller you can access the shared members, including newsData

**newsFeed Directive Controller**

```
  vm.addPost = function(newPost) {
    var currentPost = vm.currentPost;
    currentPost.created_at = new Date();
    currentPost.content = ""; //clear post textarea
    console.log(vm);
    if (newPost) {
      var postToAdd = {
        type: vm.poststype,
        content: newPost
      };
      newsFeedService.postCurrentPost(postToAdd).then(function(data) {
        vm.newsData = data;
      });
    }
  };
```

So there's the explanation, but [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/lDQ1DcFEEud6gxcNs8Nq?p=preview) it is in action.